# How to check WebSecurity 'Password Reset Token ID' validity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, webmatrix

I've been looking for a method from WebSecurity library to check the validity of the reset password token before open a reset password page for users, but unfortunately no luck!

the only thing that I've found so far is

> WebSecurity.ResetPassword('new password', 'token id');

This method resets the password using a new password and if the token is not valid it will return a false value which is good but in my case I need to only check the validity of the ResetTokenId not resetting a password and that's it.

So I was wondering if anyone knows any other methods or extensions that could help me with checking the validity of the token id?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [WebSecurity.GetUserIdFromPasswordResetToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.getuseridfrompasswordresettoken%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) to find a matching user ID. If the value is -1, you don't have a valid token.

Comment: Seems like WebSecurity will only return -1 if no UserId matching the Token was found, but will still return the UserId if the Token itself has expired